# Creating SQL Statements from a Text File - C#

Tags: c#, sql, string

Good morning,

I´m trying to create a program to create statements in a .Sql document but i´m having some troubles.

this is my code so far:

```
string[] filas = File.ReadAllLines("c:\\temp\\Statements.txt");
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("c:\\temp\\Statements.sql");
                foreach (string fila in filas)
                {
                    string sql = "INSERT ";
                    string[] campos = fila.Split(' ');

                    if (campos[0]== "1A")
                    {
                        sql += " INTO TABLE1 (field1) VALUES (" + campos[1] + ");";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sql += " INTO TABLE2 (field1,field2,field3) VALUES (" + campos[1] + "," + campos[2] + "," + campos[3] + ");";
                    }
                    sw.WriteLine(sql);
                }

                sw.Close();
                {
```

the thing is:

I need to read a txt document (the lenght will change), and then transform it to a sql document with all the statements,  there are only two tipes of lines starting in "1A" or "2B", example:

**1A123456  456,67


2B123456  mr awesome  great strt   germany


1A123456  456,67


2B123456  mr awesome  great strt   germany


2B123456  mr awesome  great strt   germany


1A123456  456,67


1A123456  456,67**

then im trying to "transform" that information on "inserts":

```
INSERT  INTO TABLE1 (REF,MONEY) VALUES (A123456,456,67);
INSERT  INTO TABLE2 (REF,NAME,ADR) VALUES (B123456,mr awesome,great strt);
INSERT  INTO TABLE1 (REF,MONEY) VALUES (A123456,456,67);
INSERT  INTO TABLE2 (REF,NAME,ADR) VALUES (B123456,mr awesome,great strt);
INSERT  INTO TABLE2 (REF,NAME,ADR) VALUES (B123456,mr awesome,great strt);
INSERT  INTO TABLE1 (REF,MONEY) VALUES (A123456,456,67);
INSERT  INTO TABLE1 (REF,MONEY) VALUES (A123456,456,67);
```

my code is not working so well... i hope someone can help me a litte :).

regards.

Comment: How exactly does your logic work to translate a non-comma separated string (e.g. `B123456 mr awesome great strt germany`) into comma-separated values (`B123456,mr awesome,great strt`)?

Comment: Hmm..I think i've seen this question before... :)

Comment: Hi pikoh!, yes this is your code, but im having some problems and i dont want to overwhelm you with more questions on the spanish section, you can help me if you wish here or not, (sorry about Y_Y)

Comment: Well,first of all for what i see, you may use just the first character to choose which `INSERT` command to use. But your biggest problem, as @decPL already told, is that you can't split your input string if the input field values are not separated by another character (a comma for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I could not see space between 1A and 123456 . So  if (campos[0]== "1A") will not work. Use contains method to do this check - if (campos[0].contains("1A"). you can alternately evaluate using startswith

Secondly you need to split 1A123456 to get A123456 .. you can use substring or similar functions for same. (Same for 2B)

Thirdly, you are splitting the string with ' ' - this could result in many more string than your anticipated strings.  2B123456 mr awesome great strt germany  - in this case mr awesome great strt are all different. You need to put in logic to concatenate  campos[1] & campos[2] and campos[3] & campos[1=4] in the case of 2B ....

Fourthly for the 1A case you need to split  campos[1] using , as delimiter to get the two values you want

Hope this provides you enough guidance to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

After some research and with the help from anil and Pikoh i found a good solution:

```
string mydate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
                    string AÑO = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy");
                    string MES = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM");
                    string DIA = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd");
                    string sql = "INSERT ";
                    string[] campos = fila.Split(' ');

                    if (campos[0].StartsWith("1H"))
                    {

                        sql += "INTO TABLE (VALUES,VALUES,VALUES) VALUES (" + "'" + mydate + "'" + "," + "'" + campos[0].Substring(1, 8) + "'" + "," + "'" + campos[0].Substring(9, 7) + "'" + "," + "'" + campos[8] + "'" + ");";
```

Inserting data and manipulating strings was good, but now i have the last problem,

**what happen if i need to make a "backspace" to an specific string because my logic cant pick the correct information?** regards.

Comment: What do you mean? Could you show by means of an example and point out the code too.